# Entity Framework Core - How to implement the one-to-many relationship with customized column and without foreign key?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

It is a legacy database with two tables, `Order` and `OrderLine`. From business view, one order can have multiple OrderLines. Both of the tables has one column with name 'OrderNumber', there is not any referrence between the two table and it is not possible to add the foreign key reference now. In SQL, if we want a order with related orderlines, we can use `join` based on OrderNumber column.

Now we are using EntityFramework Core. Is there any way to config the one-to-many relationship and make the Order's OrderLines list filled automatically? Thanks.

```
public class Order {
 public int Id;
 public string OrderNumber;
 public List<OrderLine> OrderLines;
 ...
}

public class OrderLine {
 public int Id;
 public string OrderNumber;
 ...
}
```

Comment: Since OrderNumber would have to be unique to work in that scenario you could try configuring EF to treat it as the PK while leaving Id as an IdentityColumn unless the Order.Id is used as a FK for other relationships within the EF domain. EF's `[Key]` does not have to be the PK for the table.

Comment: Hi @StevePy, Thanks. Shold I also add `[Key]` in both classes?

Comment: Just the Order, Orderline's Key would remain the Id column. If they shared the same Key it would be a 1-to-1 relationship. we want to represent that 1 order can have many orderLines with the same OrderNumber. The DB can still treat Order's Id as the PK, with DB First we can often just tell EF that the schema is a bit different than it actually is to work around some non-normalized scenarios. The "catch" might be if the Order ID is an auto-generated value. EF would need to still recognize it as an Identity column. I believe that can be applied to non-Key columns, the restriction is just 1 col.